# Get alarm infomation

Tags: android, alarm

I am implementing an application in which I have to display alarm info (day, time..) if it is available. Is there anybody know how to access to alarm info?
Thanks so much

Comment: I shared my solution in [here][1], hope it can help

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081573/get-alarm-infomation-and-changing-it-in-android-4-0/27616154#27616154

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
final String tag_alarm = "tag_alarm";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.alarmclock/alarm")
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
Log.i(tag_alarm, "no of records are" + c.getCount());
Log.i(tag_alarm, "no of columns are" + c.getColumnCount());
if (c != null) {
    String names[] = c.getColumnNames();
    for (String temp : names) {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            for (int j = 0; j < c.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                Log.i(tag_alarm, c.getColumnName(j);
                        + " which has value " + c.getString(j));
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: This code poses an error "permission denied". Moreover, it seems that "content://com.android.alarmclock/alarm" was changed to "content://com.android.deskclock/alarm" in API9 onwards

Comment: No, after changing the uri, it poses "permission denied" error

Comment: If i embed this code in Android source code and run image file, it can pass "permission denied" error and retrieve alarm information. Anyway, thanks your tip :)

Answer (score 3):

Result: Finally, I can retrieve alarm information by using Curious's answer as above. Moreover, when I explored Deskclock app in /packages/apps/ I found one more way to get next alarm format (I used this way to display alarm info on my LockScreen because it is more simple than Curious's one :) )

```
String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), 
                       Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nextAlarm) {
     Log.v(TAG, "nextAlarm is empty");
} else {
     Log.v(TAG, "nextAlarm is :" + nextAlarm);
}
```

The next alarm format like this:

```
Sat 09:00
```

The disadvantage point is that it can only run in system environment (you have to embed them to Android source -> build it and run by image file).